# In-App purchase resubscribe in ionic cordova plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, cordova-plugin-purchase

I created app with In-App purchase using [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) plugin on ionic angular. After subscription product for one year! user cancelled subscription from Android manage subscription section, subscription still valid for one year from purchase date.

So now I need to give user some options. I want to show resubscribe / continue button to user. But I can't see any option there in plugin. I would like to show special content like you have cancelled, but you can enjoy our service until expiry [date]. If you change your mind, please resubscribe(button) to our service.

I'm also wondering, Is it possible to cancel subscription from app itself, we currently taking user to manage subscriptions page.